# Android: Getting different style softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In my application I my getting different style soft keyboard for ex at one part of my app I am getting this

[image]

and at other part

[image]

but I want it to be same for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same keyboard with just different action button. So you are basically looking for

```
android:imeOptions
```

as documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#imeOptions

Answer (score 0):

This particular difference is due to the fact that, one of your EditText (text boxes are called EditTexts in Android) is a single line one, where the other is not. Set the property

```
android:lines="1"
```

in your EditTex's xml tag, and you will see second keyboard for all such EditTexts. But as @Marcin answered, learn the input types correctly, and you will find the differences between them.